# Exim forward file piping to php - error 127, unable to exec or command does not exist?

Tags: php, pipe, exim

I'm trying to pipe all emails going to hi@mydomain.com, to a script. I'm using exim, and a .forward file.

### Here is my forward file, in the 'hi' directory:

## Exim filter

### pipe "/home/web/servers/mydomain.com/htdocs/scripts/email_receiver.php"

I'm getting the following error:

Child process of address_pipe transport returned 127 (could mean unable to exec or command does not exist) from command: /home/web/servers/mydomain.com/htdocs/scripts/email_receiver.php

When I log in as 'hi', I have no problem executing that script (currently 777 permissions). The top of the script starts with: #!/usr/bin/php -q.

Any ideas? I've tried many various versions of that forward file ("pipe" vs. |, removing line 1, quotes/no quotes, adding the absolute path to php) - but I'm consistently getting this error. What could this be? Thanks :)

Comment: What user is exim running as?  Does this user have at least execute permissions to all the directories in the full path?  If it doesn't, it can't traverse them and reach your script.

Comment: As far as I understand, the script runs as 'hi'. 'hi' is in the web group, and every directory in the full path has execute permission to the web group.

Comment: Ah, I see.  The reason I asked is because my exim install runs all pipe commands as `nobody` for security reasons, which has caught me off guard more than once with the exact same error.  Do you have any root jails setup that involve exim somehow?

Comment: Hey, I'm a bit of a newbie here - what should I do if it is running as nobody? I'd like to try that, I'm not sure how to check how exim is running those pipe commands (I just read that it should be running as "hi" online). I don't think I have any root jails - I set this server (CentOS) up myself with the defaults - how can I check for that though? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: So I explicitly set the user to 'hi' in the address_pipe transport - still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, another CentOS user, we use it too. I doubt it would have rooted anything by default.  So your user is now explicitly set to hi, so that should rule out permissions errors.  I'm going to go look at one of my working setups and see if I notice anything glaring.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't seem to reproduce this behavior.  Your filter definition looks correct.  In a last-ditch effort, you could try to `chmod a+x` all the directories in the path just to be absolutely sure it's not a permissions issue. (exim not setting the user as expected, and so on.)  If that doesn't work, maybe try asking in ServerFault.

Comment: Ah, I just saw 'more comments' here - I'm also a stack overflow newbie - thanks for your help! Let me ask about the nameservers: I set the MX record to mail.domain.com, and mail A record to my IP address - with no other configuration to direct mail to the mailserver - is that correct? I assume since I'm getting the errors in exim, that it's receiving the emails just fine - right? Thanks for the ServerFault tip, I'll try that too.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: SELinux was making it so that the user 'hi' couldn't execute php. Turning SELinux off solved my problem. Thanks for your help. :)